# Change single value in row directly

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working with the SQL database functionality in Android, but in general my SQL knowledge is very much beginner level.

Currently, I store a selection of values for different items in a ContentValues object. If a single value changes for an item, I regenerate the ContentValues object again, changing the single value that has been modified, and calling:

`db.replace(TABLE_CONTENT, null, values)`

where db is a writiable SQL database and values is a ContentValues object. Is this a necessary step? Is it possible to modify the value that changed directly without having to reload the entire ContentValues object again, say by specifying a row and column index?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method requires that you have some unique index (or a primary key).

To update only some columns, use [`update`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).
You can put into the `ContentValues` only those columns that you want to change.
To specify which record(s) to change, use the `whereClause` parameter with something like `ID = 42`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go today. I'm hoping there will be some visible speed-up by using this now.